# I'm getting a 404 error when I click the button

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, razorpay

The react app is starting but as soon as I enter the "Pay 500" button, A 404 error appears.[This is the error I'm facing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack)

[button[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwImh.png).imgur.com/KXEOb.png

[displayRazorpay function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryMxg.png)
I'm not able to post code because stack overflow gives me an error saying There's too much code.

```
     return (
<div className='App'>
  <header className='App-header'>
    <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
    <p> React !</p>
    <button className='App-link' onClick={displayRazorpay}>
      Pay ₹500
    </button>
  </header>
</div>
```

);

```
async function displayRazorpay() {
    const res = await loadScript(
      'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js'
    );

    if (!res) {
      alert('Razorpay SDK failed to load. Are you online?');
      return;
    }

    const result = await axios.post('/payment/orders');

    if (!result) {
      alert('Server error. Are you online?');
      return;
    }

    const { amount, id: order_id, currency } = result.data;

    const options = {
      key: 'rzp_test_ebAiytazvr1MvI', // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
      amount: amount.toString(),
      currency: currency,
      name: 'Anand',
      description: 'Test Transaction',
      image: { logo },
      order_id: order_id,
      handler: async function (response) {
        const data = {
          orderCreationId: order_id,
          razorpayPaymentId: response.razorpay_payment_id,
          razorpayOrderId: response.razorpay_order_id,
          razorpaySignature: response.razorpay_signature,
        };

        const result = await axios.post('/payment/success', data);

        alert(result.data.msg);
      },
      prefill: {
        name: 'Anand',
        email: 'mmmmmmmmmmm@gmail.com',
        contact: '91111111111',
      },
      notes: {
        address: '..............',
      },
      theme: {
        color: '#616161',
      },
    };
```

Comment: Please share the code that makes the request

Comment: Have you worked on with react-router , please share your code which help in analysing the reason

Comment: Ok fine dont share the whole code insted share only part of pay 500 alone . And please let know have you used any react router to move to other page. some thing like this : [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router)

Comment: Hello, @Nithin-Techidiots . Thank you. I have updated the question. I have used async react router .

Comment: Also put function for displayRazorpay

Comment: check whether `const { amount, id: order_id, currency } = result.data;` contain any datas